# php function based on a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make a ranking PHP function based on this query:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    , id, name, avatar, views
    FROM users
    , (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS dummy
    WHERE users.group_id = 5
    ORDER BY views DESC
```

Something like:

```
function $rank {
    $rank = SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id, name, avatar, views FROM users, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS dummy WHERE users.group_id = 5 ORDER BY views DESC;
    return $rank;
}
```

And then to echo the rank on my website. The idea is to get user rank on every place i need to use it (users list or user profile)

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Please specify.

Comment: i hope im more specific now. Regards!

Comment: Hmm....I still dont understand your question fully, but I think that you don't know how to run a query using PHP, and you want someone to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This should do the trick.

```
<?php
function getUserRank($group) {
$query = "SELECT id, name, avatar, views "
       . "FROM users "
       . "WHERE users.group_id = :group "
       . "ORDER BY views DESC";

// Execute query. This is the PDO version
$query = $db->prepare($query);
$query->bindValue(':group', $group);
$query->execute();

return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
} 

// Call function and pass the group ID over;
$list = getUserRank($group);

for ($i = 1; $i <= (count($list)); $i++) {
echo "$i -> $list->[name] -> $list->[$avatar] -> $list->[views]";
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont think its going to work because the rank is based on profile views. So i want to be able to show: User_id1 = 100 profile views = rank 1,  User_id5 = 88 profile views = rank 2

Comment: So you want to select rank based on the users profile views? As in, if the user has 75 views, there's a rank "Bronze" for example for anyone between 0 and 100 views? I think you need to show your DB tables for us

Comment: mysql row is called "users" and it contains the following values "id" , "name" , "views"  , "avatar"

Comment: Edited; Does this help at all?